# Laravel 4 (Eloquent) Erro ao deletar registros

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Olá, nesse código abaixo eu faço um delete no banco de dados dos registros selecionados em uma lista de chekboxes.

Tenho um array de Ids que é montado da seguinte forma:

```
Array (
    [0] => 810
    [1] => 811
)
```

Em cima desse array eu faço um foreach busco cada registro e chamo o método de exclusão, código completo abaixo:

```
public function destroy_download($id = 0){
    $ids = ($id >= 1) ? array($id) : Input::get('ids');

    if( ! empty($ids) ){
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $download = Download::find($id);
            $download->delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Isso deveria funcionar corretamente, no entanto dá o seguinte erro:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Call to a member function delete() on a non-object
```

na linha:

```
$download->delete();
```

É como se o registro não tivesse sido encontrado.

Ele remove o registro no banco de dados só que acontece esse erro, alguém consegue imaginar o que seja?

O Array está correto, já debuguei mas sempre dá isso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
public function destroy_download($id = 0){
    $ids = ($id >= 1) ? array($id) : Input::get('ids');

    if( ! empty($ids) ){
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            try {
                Download::findOrFail($id)->delete();
            } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esse código tentará excluir o id, caso não encontre esse registro, segue para o próximo.

**Sugestão**: Acho uma boa rever esse método, da maneira que está temos verificações desnecessárias da variável `$ids`

```
public function destroyDownloads(){
    $ids = Input::get('ids');

    // Não é um array? Aborta a função
    if(!is_array($ids)){
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($ids as $id){
        $this->deleteDownload($id);
    }

    // Ou returne um Response::make()
    return true;

}

private function deleteDownload($id){

    try {
        Download::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
        // Caso queira verificar erros no futuro, basta verificar com um if
        // o retorno de $this->deleteDownload($id), se for falso o registro não existia
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei usar o try catch, mas ele não lança uma exceção ModelNotFoundException. Ele dá erro no $download->delete(), e não entra no catch. Tá bizarro isso.
Segue um printa pra você ver: http://imageshack.com/a/img600/2163/dfzi.png

Comment: O mais estranho é que se ao invés de eu chamar o método     $download->delete(), eu fizer echo $download->name funciona, não dá erro algum, ele exibe os nomes.

Comment: @Jarbas tente postar um var_dump do objeto `$download` e postar o seu model `Download`

Comment: postei no pastebin. O Dump é do objeto sem chamar o ->delete(), porque ai não dá erro.

Objeto $download: http://pastebin.com/dwGcStJg
Model: http://pastebin.com/vSDGsxt7

Comment: Estranho... vou tentar reproduzir o erro aqui

Answer (score 0):

Confirme se o ID do objeto existe, interpretando um pouco o resultado, parece a função `Download::find($id);` retorna uma string/null quando o `Id` não existe, consequentemente quando voce tenta chamar o método `delete()` gera esse erro.

Crie uma verificação que confirme se o ID realmente existe antes de chamar a `delete()`.

Comment: Infelizmente não é isso, eu testei.

Comment: @Jarbas, atualizei a resposta

Comment: Rogerio, eu já fiz todos os testes possíveis, testei se o objeto existe e etc. Esses ids vem de um grid que lista os registros dessa tabela. O Problema é que ele deleta o registro que dá erro.